# How to display todays date in my full calendar agendaDay of today

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have a full calendar and I want to display the current date on my left side of the screen which is a defaultView: 'agendaDay'.

Only by clicking the next or prev btn I can able to view the **agendaDay**.

Below is the screen what I am wanting the result, also I have attached a Fielded for it. Please suggest.

[image: FullCalendar]

jsfiddle.net/wpL7ygdu

Answer (score 0):

Did you try set calendar to today's date?

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: new Date()
});
```

Comment: still showing blank and by clicking next its showing calender month-wise now and its not in agendaDay.

Comment: Is it possible for you to prepare working fiddle? The one above doesn't show calendar.